# Are intermediate states just mathematical constructs?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering, feynman-diagrams, vacuum

In the vacuum state, particles and antiparticles can spontaneously emerge as virtual pairs due to the uncertainty principle. These virtual particles have a brief existence before they annihilate each other. This process is a manifestation of vacuum fluctuations.

Similarly, in particle interactions, intermediate states involve virtual particles that can exist for a short time before contributing to the overall interaction process. These virtual particles mediate the exchange of momentum and energy between the initial and final states of the particles involved.

If the intermediate state is represented by virtual particles, should we distinguish the actual physical process of the in-between, intermediate state from the vacuum state?

Are intermediate states just mathematical constructs only useful for calculating; or they have a physical significance within the framework of quantum field theory?

We cannot think of the intermediate state as the vacuum state despite having the same description involving virtual particles that cannot be observed due to their brief existence?